# handling soap message tag attributes with wash_out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, soap, rubygems, wsdl, wash-out

wash_out is a great gem for a soap service, but can't figure out how to read or set attributes on the SOAP message tag, as in:

```
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://v1.example.com/">
    <env:Body>
        <SomeTag ID="ABC321" Type="Basic">
           Some text here
        </SomeTag>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

any help would be much appreciated

---

This small modification to the wash_out gem allows me to render tag attributes for document style wsdl:

```
def wsdl_data_options(param) 
  case controller.soap_config.wsdl_style 
  when 'rpc' 
    { :"xsi:type" => param.namespaced_type } 
  when 'document'
    attributes = { }
    if param.struct? 
      if !param.multiplied 
        param.map.each do |p| 
          if p.name[0] == '@' 
            attributes[p.name.gsub('@','')] = p.value 
            param.map.delete(p)
          end
        end
      end
    end
    attributes
  end
end
```

Now my soap_action looks like this:

```
soap_service :wsdl_style => 'document'
soap_action :incoming_request,
            :args => {'HotelSearchCriteria' => {'HotelID' => :string}},
            :return => {'RoomTypes' => [{'RoomType' => {'@RoomCode' => :string, 'RoomDescription' => {'@Name' => :string, 'Text' => :string}}}]},
            :response_tag => 'MyResponse'

def incoming_request
  render :soap => {'RoomTypes' => [{'RoomType' => {'@RoomCode' => "#{@room_code}", 'RoomDescription' => {'@Name' => "#{@room_name}", 'Text' => "#{@room_text}"}}}]}
end
```

Rendering the following soap message:

```
<soap:Body>
  <MyResponse>
     <RoomTypes>
        <RoomType RoomCode="SGL">
           <RoomDescription Name="Single Room">
              <Text>One King Bedroom</Text>
           </RoomDescription>
        </RoomType>
     </RoomTypes>
  </MyResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Instead of:

```
<soap:Body>
  <MyResponse>
     <RoomTypes>
        <RoomType>
           <RoomCode>SGL</RoomCode>
           <RoomDescription>
              <Name>Single Room</Name>
              <Text>One King Bedroom</Text>
           </RoomDescription>
        </RoomType>
     </RoomTypes>
  </MyResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

@inossidabile 
Let me know your thougts

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Normally you shouldn't be going down to XML at all with SOAP. Why do you want to read it?

Comment: @inossidabile Thank You for replying. I'm trying to implement a soap interface to a third-party service that is expecting some of the returned values to be passed as tag attributes. Here is a example:

      <RoomTypes>
        <RoomType RoomCode="SGL">
          <RoomDescription RoomName="Single Room">
            <Text>Bedding is Queen sized bed. Continental breakfast for each guest.</Text>
          </RoomDescription>
        </RoomType>
      </RoomTypes>  

I can't figure out how to set the values corresponding to RoomCode and RoomName in the above example.

Comment: @inossidabile Made a small modification to the wash_out gem in order to render tag attributes: `def wsdl_data_options(param)
    case controller.soap_config.wsdl_style
    when 'rpc'
      { :"xsi:type" => param.namespaced_type }
    when 'document'
      attributes = { }
      if param.struct?
        if !param.multiplied
          param.map.each do |p|
            if p.name[0] == '@'
              attributes[p.name.gsub('@','')] = p.value
              param.map.delete(p)
            end  
          end
        end
      end
      attributes
    end
  end`

Comment: Can you please paste it somewhere like github gists?

Comment: @inossidabile please see my recent edit above

Comment: Okay. I don't see this solving your issue. It will add that into WSDL, yes, but attributes will simply be dropped by dispatcher. Are you saying this works for you?

Comment: @inossidabile yes, it works, although I had to change the naming convention because WSDL does not like element names that start with a special character, but other than that, it works

Comment: @inossidabile and @vic700208 - So what is the status on this? I would also like to have a parameter an element - so e.g. `<xsd:attribute type="xsd:integer" name="id"/>`